# SendMessage is not working

Tags: c, dll, sendmessage

I am trying to build a dll (in Clr flavor) to feed a windows app with intraday stock quotes. The dll is loaded by the stock app then one of its exported functions will launch a downloader/producer to get data. In the second step, once the data received by the dll, an updater/consumer will notify the stock app thru SendMessage.

I have tested in many ways that the downloading part is working as expected (with or without thread support) so getting data is no problem. In single iteration case (test1 below), right after snapshot quotes available, updater succeeds in its mission and the windows UI gets updated. Now to keep getting new quotes, I put the downloader and updater function calls inside a loop (test2 below). This time, downloader works continuously but the SendMessage in the updater hung there leaving the windows UI un-updated until it gets out of the loop.

Here is the test codes and updater code (let's put aside the downloder as we know it is working):

```
// test1: single iteration, sequential, simple insert only
// result: will update the stock app after quote download
void test1(HWND hwnd, UINT Msg)
{
    producer->DownloadStocks();
    prepareData(hwnd, Msg, 100);
}

// test2: one iteration of insert followed by updates upon quote download
// result: will update the stock app ONLY after it is out of the while loop
//         update in test1 is blocked, too.
void test2(HWND hwnd, UINT Msg)
{
    test1(hwnd, Msg);
    int i = 0;
    while (i<10)
    {
       producer->DownloadStocks();
       prepareData(hwnd, Msg, 100);
       i++;
    }
}


    void prepareData(HWND hwnd, UINT Msg, int timeout)
    {

        DateTime origin = DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        RCV_DATA rcv_data;
        float vv = 0;
        rcv_data.m_bDISK = FALSE;
        rcv_data.m_nPacketNum = 1;
        rcv_data.m_wDataType = RCV_REPORT;
        RCV_REPORT_STRUCTEx data;
        data.m_fBuyPrice[1] = 0;
        data.m_fBuyVolume[1] = 0;
        ......
        data.m_wMarket = (WORD)NQ_MARKET_EX;

        while (consumer->received_data())
        {
            Console::WriteLine("*********************************");

            while (consumer->NextRow())
            {

                sprintf(data.m_szLabel, "%s", consumer->GetValue("symbol"));
                .......
                data.m_fSellPrice[0] = getVal("ask");
                data.m_fSellVolume[0] = getVal("asksize");

                rcv_data.m_pReport = &data;
                printf("\nsending update for %s", data.m_szLabel);
                SendMessage(hwnd, Msg, (WPARAM)RCV_REPORT, (LPARAM)&rcv_data);

            }
        }

    }
```

I know SendMessage is in synchr mode. Is it blocked by something or the message processing is too slow? What can I do to work around this? Should I consider threading for both downloader and updater? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your window gets updated on next Paint event, which it would be able to process if thread is free. In single thread, only after your loop/function is finished it can get/process other events. You need to do multithreading..

Comment: Deadlock is a common hazard when you use SendMessage().  You'll need to use a debugger, find out what the thread that owns the window is doing.  Always favor PostMessage() instead.

Comment: @Ashish Negi, I tried pthread using the consumer/producer pattern. It won't work.

Comment: @Hans Passant I tried PostMessage, there is no update outside the loop

Comment: if you are using multiple threads, try sending WM_PAINT event after the work is done. but make sure to send this event to the UI thread.

Comment: @Ashish Negi I came across a suggestion of using UpdateWindow(). (MSDN) says it "updates the client area of the specified window by sending a WM_PAINT message to the window"  so I add it right after SendMessage, now I can see continuous update of the window app with new quotes. However, the app's UI remains inaccessible, i.e, I cannot click on any menu items. Should I consider running the update as a background thread/worker?

Comment: @Ben yes.. absolutely.. Ideally UI thread should always be free i.e. no code running and waiting for user events.. For your problem there are other hacks available but i would suggest you to do it the right way of using background thread for real work..

Comment: @Ashish Negi I added a thread for the updater. Although it frees up the UI, it failed to send message to the UI for update. I think this is cross-thread message sending. How can I do it the right way? Any code sample? Thanks.

Comment: @Ben i hope that your `RCV_REPORT` event is being received ? For redraw you can use `InvalidateRect` see http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/107251/ .. If this does not work.. there is something else is wrong in your code.. which would be another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already sending your data to UI thread by `SendMessage`, you can send `WM_PAINT` event to that window also. You can do this with [UpdateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [InvalidateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This would cause view to refresh after your updates.

Cross thread redraw events are explained here with some code: [redraw-from-another-thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/107251/)

You need to keep UI thread always free for user interactivity.
Therefore, do your blocking work (like downloading) in the background threads. [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) can work cross-platform, if you can use `c++11`.

Comment: It's been a while. Finally, I got most problems solved. To do that, I spawn a thread to update the data by "SendMessage" to the UI through a HWND and a pre-defined message. So, Thanks for the suggestions from all, particularly from @Ashish Negi

Comment: Glad that it helped.. :) Great perseverance @Ben

Answer (score 0):

the 'while' loop and the called functions within that loop are hogging the CPU.

suggest a voluntary release of the CPU in each iteration of the while loop.

perhaps by calling nsleep()

Comment: hum, Placing sleep in different places for various length doesn't seem to unblock the update.